# Iterating the rows and cells of XERO API JSON response via Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I am using the apps script to fetch the data of XERO account system via API

However I could retrieve the data and the result was a complex nested table structure. This intricate structure I need to write in the form of a 2d table (rows and columns)

I am unable iterate each and every nested values. Is there a way to get every possible nested cell values of rows and columns and orgazize to the parsed data in the form of a 2d array?

I have tried with

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
<script>
var x = {
 "Reports": [{
  "ReportID": "TrialBalance",
  "ReportName": "Trial Balance",
  "ReportType": "TrialBalance",
  "ReportTitles": [
   "Trial Balance",
   "Demo Company (NZ)",
   "As at 30 August 2010"
  ],
  "ReportDate": "21 February 2011",
  "UpdatedDateUTC": "\/Date(1519357171249)\/",
  "Rows": [{
   "RowType": "Header",
   "Cells": [{
     "Value": "Account"
    },
    {
     "Value": "Debit"
    },
    {
     "Value": "Credit"
    },
    {
     "Value": "YTD Debit"
    },
    {
     "Value": "YTD Credit"
    }
   ]
  }, {
   "RowType": "Section",
   "Title": "Revenue",
   "Rows": [{
    "RowType": "Row",
    "Cells": [{
      "Value": "Interest Income (270)",
      "Attributes": [{
       "Value": "e9482110-7245-4a76-bfe2-14500495a076",
       "Id": "account"
      }]
     }, {
      "Attributes": [{
       "Value": "e9482110-7245-4a76-bfe2-14500495a076",
       "Id": "account"
      }]
     }, {
      "Value": "0.00",
      "Attributes": [{
       "Value": "e9482110-7245-4a76-bfe2-14500495a076",
       "Id": "account"
      }]
     },
     {
      "Attributes": [{
       "Value": "e9482110-7245-4a76-bfe2-14500495a076",
       "Id": "account"
      }]
     },
     {
      "Value": "500.00",
      "Attributes": [{
       "Value": "e9482110-7245-4a76-bfe2-14500495a076",
       "Id": "account"
      }]
     }
    ]
   }, {
    "RowType": "Row",
    "Cells": [{
     "Value": "Sales (200)",
     "Attributes": [{
      "Value": "5040915e-8ce7-4177-8d08-fde416232f18",
      "Id": "account"
     }]
    }, {
     "Attributes": [{
      "Value": "5040915e-8ce7-4177-8d08-fde416232f18",
      "Id": "account"
     }]
    }, {
     "Value": "12180.25",
     "Attributes": [{
      "Value": "5040915e-8ce7-4177-8d08-fde416232f18",
      "Id": "account"
     }]
    }, {
     "Attributes": [{
      "Value": "5040915e-8ce7-4177-8d08-fde416232f18",
      "Id": "account"
     }]
    }, {
     "Value": "20775.53",
     "Attributes": [{
      "Value": "5040915e-8ce7-4177-8d08-fde416232f18",
      "Id": "account"
     }]
    }]
   }]
  }, {
   "RowType": "Section",
   "Rows": [{
    "RowType": "SummaryRow",
    "Cells": [{
      "Value": "Total"
     },
     {
      "Value": "17447.02"
     },
     {
      "Value": "17447.02"
     },
     {
      "Value": "33459.76"
     },
     {
      "Value": "33459.76"
     }
    ]
   }]
  }]
 }]
}

    var r = x.Reports[0].Rows;
    var n = r.length;

for(var i=0;i<n;i++)
{

 if(r[i].hasOwnProperty("Cells"))
   {
     var c = r[i].Cells;
        var row = []
        for(var j=0;j<c.length;j++)
        {
            row.push([c[j].Value]);
        }
        console.log(row)
    }
    else
    {
     var rr = r[i].Rows
        var nn = r[i].Rows.length
        for(var k=0;k<nn;k++)
  {
         if(rr[k].hasOwnProperty("Cells"))
            {
             var cc = rr[k].Cells;
          var rowrow = [];
                  for(var l=0;l<cc.length;l++)
                  {
                      rowrow.push([cc[l].Value]);
                  }
            }
            
         
        }
        console.log(rowrow)
 }

  
}


</script>
</body>

</html>
```

**UPDATE**

From the Tom 's suggestion How do I get 2d array from the below snippet?

```
    function test(json) {
var it = new JIterator(json);
var i = 0;
console.log("DepthFirst traverse:");
do {
    console.log(i++ + '\t' + it.Level + '\t' + it.Path().join('.') + '\t' + it.KeyDots(), (it.Value() instanceof Object) ? (it.Value() instanceof Array ? "[]" : "{}") : it.Value());
} while (it.DepthFirst());
}
```

Comment: Made a simple iterator IIFE, source here https://github.com/eltomjan/ETEhomeTools/blob/master/HTM_HTA/JSON_Iterator_IIFE.js demo here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56698728/how-to-traverse-json-object-random-direction/56698756#56698756 There are 2 iterators, level, path info and it uses double linked list inside (build by recursion in constructor).

Comment: Thank you, I have added a UPDATE question, could you point me please

Comment: Maybe this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54279135/how-can-i-cleanly-present-well-formed-names-keys-and-values-from-json-in-javascr#57389772 uses newer version, but not sure what is your supposed output and do not have computer now, is it ok to do on monday or tomorow ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite tricky JSON and traversing, but what about this ?

```js
function demoPrint() {
  var it = new JIterator(x());
  var rows = [];
  do {
    if(it.Key() == "Cells") {
      var col = [];
      var returnLevel = it.Level;
      it.DepthFirst();
      it.DepthFirst();
      var rowLevel = it.Level;
      do {
        if (it.Level == rowLevel) {
          if (it.Key() == "Value") col.push(it.Value());
          //else col.push("?"); // missing Value(s)
        } 
      } while (it.DepthFirst() && it.Level > returnLevel)
      rows.push(col);
      while (it.Level != returnLevel && it.DepthFirst());
    }
  } while (it.DepthFirst());
  var res = "<TABLE border=1>";
  for(var i in rows) {
    res += "<TR><TD>"
    res += rows[i].join("</TD><TD>");
    res += "</TD><TR>"
  }
  res += "</TABLE>";
  document.body.innerHTML = res;
}
function x() {
  return {
    "Reports": [{
      "ReportID": "TrialBalance",
      "ReportName": "Trial Balance",
      "ReportType": "TrialBalance",
      "ReportTitles": [
        "Trial Balance",
        "Demo Company (NZ)",
        "As at 30 August 2010"
      ],
      "ReportDate": "21 February 2011",
      "UpdatedDateUTC": "\/Date(1519357171249)\/",
      "Rows": [{
        "RowType": "Header",
        "Cells": [{
          "Value": "Account"
        },
        {
          "Value": "Debit"
        },
        {
          "Value": "Credit"
        },
        {
          "Value": "YTD Debit"
        },
        {
          "Value": "YTD Credit"
        }
        ]
      }, {
        "RowType": "Section",
        "Title": "Revenue",
        "Rows": [{
          "RowType": "Row",
          "Cells": [{
            "Value": "Interest Income (270)",
            "Attributes": [{
              "Value": "e9482110-7245-4a76-bfe2-14500495a076",
              "Id": "account"
            }]
          }, {
            "Attributes": [{
              "Value": "e9482110-7245-4a76-bfe2-14500495a076",
              "Id": "account"
            }]
          }, {
            "Value": "0.00",
            "Attributes": [{
              "Value": "e9482110-7245-4a76-bfe2-14500495a076",
              "Id": "account"
            }]
          },
          {
            "Attributes": [{
              "Value": "e9482110-7245-4a76-bfe2-14500495a076",
              "Id": "account"
            }]
          },
          {
            "Value": "500.00",
            "Attributes": [{
              "Value": "e9482110-7245-4a76-bfe2-14500495a076",
              "Id": "account"
            }]
          }
          ]
        }, {
          "RowType": "Row",
          "Cells": [{
            "Value": "Sales (200)",
            "Attributes": [{
              "Value": "5040915e-8ce7-4177-8d08-fde416232f18",
              "Id": "account"
            }]
          }, {
            "Attributes": [{
              "Value": "5040915e-8ce7-4177-8d08-fde416232f18",
              "Id": "account"
            }]
          }, {
            "Value": "12180.25",
            "Attributes": [{
              "Value": "5040915e-8ce7-4177-8d08-fde416232f18",
              "Id": "account"
            }]
          }, {
            "Attributes": [{
              "Value": "5040915e-8ce7-4177-8d08-fde416232f18",
              "Id": "account"
            }]
          }, {
            "Value": "20775.53",
            "Attributes": [{
              "Value": "5040915e-8ce7-4177-8d08-fde416232f18",
              "Id": "account"
            }]
          }]
        }]
      }, {
        "RowType": "Section",
        "Rows": [{
          "RowType": "SummaryRow",
          "Cells": [{
            "Value": "Total"
          },
          {
            "Value": "17447.02"
          },
          {
            "Value": "17447.02"
          },
          {
            "Value": "33459.76"
          },
          {
            "Value": "33459.76"
          }
          ]
        }]
      }]
    }]
  };
}

// https://github.com/eltomjan/ETEhomeTools/blob/master/HTM_HTA/JSON_Iterator_IIFE.js
'use strict';
var JNode = (function (jsNode) {

    function JNode(_parent, _pred, _key, _value) {
        this.parent = _parent;
        this.pred = _pred;
        this.node = null;
        this.next = null;
        this.key = _key;
        this.value = _value;
    }
    JNode.prototype.HasOwnKey = function () { return this.key && (typeof this.key != "number"); }
    JNode.prototype.HasStringValue = function () { return !(this.value instanceof Object); }

    return JNode;
})();

var JIterator = (function (json) {
    var root, current, maxLevel = -1;

    function JIterator(json, parent) {
        if (parent === undefined) parent = null;
        var pred = null, localCurrent;
        for (var child in json) {
            var obj = json[child] instanceof Object;
            if (json instanceof Array) child = parseInt(child); // non-associative array
            if (!root) root = localCurrent = new JNode(parent, null, child, json[child]);
            else {
                localCurrent = new JNode(parent, pred, child, obj ? ((json[child] instanceof Array) ? [] : {}) : json[child]);
            }
            if (pred) pred.next = localCurrent;
            if (parent && parent.node == null) parent.node = localCurrent;
            pred = localCurrent;
            if (obj) {
                var memPred = pred;
                JIterator(json[child], pred);
                pred = memPred;
            }
        }
        if (this) {
            current = root;
            this.Level = 0;
        }
    }

    JIterator.prototype.Current = function () { return current; }
    JIterator.prototype.SetCurrent = function (newCurrent) { current = newCurrent; }
    JIterator.prototype.Parent = function () {
        var retVal = current.parent;
        if (retVal == null) return false;
        this.Level--;
        return current = retVal;
    }
    JIterator.prototype.Pred = function () {
        var retVal = current.pred;
        if (retVal == null) return false;
        return current = retVal;
    }
    JIterator.prototype.Node = function () {
        var retVal = current.node;
        if (retVal == null) return false;
        this.Level++;
        return current = retVal;
    }
    JIterator.prototype.Next = function () {
        var retVal = current.next;
        if (retVal == null) return false;
        return current = retVal;
    }
    JIterator.prototype.Key = function () { return current.key; }
    JIterator.prototype.KeyDots = function () { return (typeof (current.key) == "number") ? "" : (current.key + ':'); }
    JIterator.prototype.Value = function () { return current.value; }
    JIterator.prototype.Reset = function () {
        current = root;
        this.Level = 0;
    }
    JIterator.prototype.RawPath = function () {
        var steps = [], level = current;
        do {
            if (level != null && level.value instanceof Object) {
                steps.push(level.key + (level.value instanceof Array ? "[]" : "{}"));
            } else {
                if (level != null) steps.push(level.key);
                else break;
            }
            level = level.parent;
        } while (level != null);
        var retVal = "";
        retVal = steps.reverse();
        return retVal;
    }
    JIterator.prototype.Path = function () {
        var steps = [], level = current;
        do {
            if (level != null && level.value instanceof Object) {
                var size = 0;
                var items = level.node;
                if (typeof (level.key) == "number") steps.push('[' + level.key + ']');
                else {
                    while (items) {
                        size++;
                        items = items.next;
                    }
                    var type = (level.value instanceof Array ? "[]" : "{}");
                    var prev = steps[steps.length - 1];
                    if (prev && prev[0] == '[') {
                        var last = prev.length - 1;
                        if (prev[last] == ']') {
                            last--;
                            if (!isNaN(prev.substr(1, last))) {
                                steps.pop();
                                size += '.' + prev.substr(1, last);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    steps.push(level.key + type[0] + size + type[1]);
                }
            } else {
                if (level != null) {
                    if (typeof (level.key) == "number") steps.push('[' + level.key + ']');
                    else steps.push(level.key);
                }
                else break;
            }
            level = level.parent;
        } while (level != null);
        var retVal = "";
        retVal = steps.reverse();
        return retVal;
    }
    JIterator.prototype.DepthFirst = function () {
        if (current == null) return 0; // exit sign
        if (current.node != null) {
            current = current.node;
            this.Level++;
            if (maxLevel < this.Level) maxLevel = this.Level;
            return 1; // moved down
        } else if (current.next != null) {
            current = current.next;
            return 2; // moved right
        } else {
            while (current != null) {
                if (current.next != null) {
                    current = current.next;
                    return 3; // returned up & moved next
                }
                this.Level--;
                current = current.parent;
            }
        }
        return 0; // exit sign
    }
    JIterator.prototype.BreadthFirst = function () {
        if (current == null) return 0; // exit sign
        if (current.next) {
            current = current.next;
            return 1; // moved right
        } else if (current.parent) {
            var level = this.Level, point = current;
            while (this.DepthFirst() && level != this.Level);
            if (current) return 2; // returned up & moved next
            do {
                this.Reset();
                level++;
                while (this.DepthFirst() && level != this.Level);
                if (current) return 3; // returned up & moved next
            } while (maxLevel >= level);
            return current != null ? 3 : 0;
        } else if (current.node) {
            current = current.node;
            return 3;
        } else if (current.pred) {
            while (current.pred) current = current.pred;
            while (current && !current.node) current = current.next;
            if (!current) return null;
            else return this.DepthFirst();
        }
    }
    JIterator.prototype.ReadArray = function () {
        var retVal = {};
        var item = current;
        do {
            if (item.value instanceof Object) {
                if (item.value.length == 0) retVal[item.key] = item.node;
                else retVal[item.key] = item;
            } else retVal[item.key] = item.value;
            item = item.next;
        } while (item != null);
        return retVal;
    }
    JIterator.prototype.FindKey = function (key) {
        var pos = current;
        while (current && current.key != key) this.DepthFirst();
        if (current.key == key) {
            var retVal = current;
            current = pos;
            return retVal;
        } else {
            current = pos;
            return null;
        }
    }

    return JIterator;
})();

demoPrint();
```

```css
table {
  border-spacing: 0px; /* small tricks 2 make rounded table simply or */
}
th {
  text-align:left; /* centered looks ugly */
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your prompt and quick help.